# Anchor not clickable with negative z-index

Tags: css

I have left side bar with properties:

```
#sidebar {
 width: 280px;
 height:100vh;
 text-align: right;
 left: 0px;
 top: 110px;
 z-index: -1;
 position: fixed;
}

#sidebar ul {
padding-top: 28px;
}

#sidebar li {
list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li a 
{
 padding: 5px 0px 4px 0px;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 35px;
 text-decoration: none;
 pointer-events: crosshair;

transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

 #sidebar ul {
 margin-right: 40px;
 }
```

With this properties I have a tab in sidebar which is not working
if i remove the z-index then it work or If I make its property to positive value again it works fine.

but in both cases i did get what i need.

Please help

- Thanks
  Prashant

Comment: So ... whats the issue, You fixed your own problem?

Comment: Nop. Still its not working. unable to click with expected result. :(

Comment: Please make a snippet or working fiddle.

Comment: You said if you give a positive value, it works right ? So why not leave it at that

Comment: "*but in both cases i did get what i need.*" - Job done, what's your question then?

Comment: I need z-index with negative value and anchor tag clickable...

Comment: Negative z-index means it's behind the html and body and any other elements as the default z-index is 0 or 1 (I'm not 100%), so it's expected that you would not be able to click on it.